# How to change div as per selected value from material UI <TextField /> dropdown in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two `divs` one is displaying by default second one is hide by default. I have one `<TextField />` dropdown list from react js material UI.

Now I want to hide first `div` and display second `div` if user selected value == 'Custom Value'

How can i do this?

My Code:-

```js
function MyComponent() {
 const inputSourceOptions = [
    { key: "Fax", value: "Fax" },
    { key: "Care Radius", value: "Care Radius" },
    { key: "Custom Value", value: "Custom Value" },
  ];
  
    const handleChangeInput = (id, event) => {
              console.log(event.target.value);
    });
    
    return (
    <>
      <TextField
                    className="ruleContainer"
                    select
                    name="rule_source"
                    label="Source"
                    variant="outlined"
                    size="small"
                    value={inputField.rule_source}
                    onChange={(event) =>
                      handleChangeInput(inputField.id, event)
                    }
                  >
                    {inputSourceOptions.map((opt) => (
                      <MenuItem key={opt.key} value={opt.key}>
                        {opt.value}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </TextField>
<div  style={{ display:'none'}}>this is div one</div>
<div>this is div two</div>
    </>
  );
}
    
    export default MyComponent;
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: The code is using something called `inputField`, but that isn't defined anywhere.  *In general* you would have three parts to this... (1) Create a state value to store your selected menu item; (2) Update that state value when the selection changes; (3) Use that state value to conditionally show the output you want to show.  The code shown makes no use of state, which is fundamental in React.  Have you tried anything at all?  Are you just looking for tutorials and examples on using state in React?

Comment: thanks @David its done with the help of state as you define here...

Comment: but I have one more question if I have to use this conditions multiple times then how can I manage? I need to define state each time ?

Comment: You can organize state however you like.  Individual values, complex objects and hierarchies, whatever you prefer.  And you can refactor repeated operations to store and re-use the results of those operations.  There's nothing about React which prevents you from defining data structures and organizing code like you would anywhere else.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?